# What could explain that platelet-rich plasma (PRP) injections are not more efficient than Autologous Blood injections to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendons, injections, prp, autologous-blood-inject

A number of RCT studies have shown that platelet-rich plasma (PRP) injections are not more efficient than autologous blood injections to treat a tendinopathy.

Example: Krogh, T., E. M. Bartels, T. Ellingsen, K. Stengaard-Pedersen, R. Buchbinder, U. Fredberg, H. Bliddal, and R. Christensen. "OP0072 Comparative effectiveness of injection therapies in lateral epicondylitis: A systematic review and network meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials." Annals of the Rheumatic Diseases 71, no. Suppl 3 (2013): 77-78. [link](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Comparative+effectiveness+of+injection+therapies+in+lateral+epicondylitis%3A+a+systematic+review+and+network+meta-analysis+of+randomized+controlled+trials&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C22&as_sdtp=) reports:

[image]

What could explain that platelet-rich plasma (PRP) injections are not more efficient than Autologous Blood injections to treat a tendinopathy?

Is that because Autologous Blood injections already maxed out the potential benefit of growth-factors?

I am mostly interested in epicondylitis (epicondylopathy).

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.